# Implicit declaration of 'memfd_create'

Tags: c, linux, gcc, clang

I'm trying to use functions from `mman.h` in my c code. The code compiles fine with g++/clang++, but when using gcc/clang it says that `memfd_create` has not been declared, however the code still runs fine.

I tried compiling online with godbolt and it's the same as locally, so I doubt it's something wrong with my setup. Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm using gcc 11.3 and clang 14.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
    int32_t fd = memfd_create("", 0);
    
    if (fd == -1) 
    {
        printf("Error creating fd\n");
        return -1;  
    }   
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compile warning:

```
main.c:9:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'memfd_create' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int32_t fd = memfd_create("", 0);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate the actual language. Also, when compiling, turn on warnings. Further, include the full error message along with the [mcve] that produced it. Note that quite a few things you can do wrong will just cause "undefined behaviour", which may include to seemingly work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_GNU_SOURCE` has to be before any `#include`. See `man feature_test_macros`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
```